# How can I group data by criteria in matplot to plot a matrix

Tags: r

To create a simple example say I'm trying to plot the matrix below and I want to plot the the matrix and have each type represented by a different color.

```
> test
  Type Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
1    1  0.50  1.50  2.50  3.50
2    1  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00
3    1  0.25  1.25  2.25  3.25
4    1  0.75  1.75  2.75  3.75
5    2  0.20  1.20  2.20  3.20
6    2  0.41  1.41  2.41  3.41
7    2  0.83  1.83  2.83  3.83
8    2  0.63  1.63  2.63  3.63


matplot(t(test[,2:5]),type='l')
```

I have tried multiple things and even tried to learn ggplot but strugglint to figure this out for my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use *Type* as `col=` actually, no need for data wrangling

```
> matplot(t(dat[, 2:5]), type='l', col=dat$Type)
```

[image]

You can also individualize colors

```
> matplot(t(dat[,2:5]), type='l', col=c('#f38126', '#878286')[dat$Type])
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Test1 = c(0.5, 
1, 0.25, 0.75, 0.2, 0.41, 0.83, 0.63), Test2 = c(1.5, 2, 1.25, 
1.75, 1.2, 1.41, 1.83, 1.63), Test3 = c(2.5, 3, 2.25, 2.75, 2.2, 
2.41, 2.83, 2.63), Test4 = c(3.5, 4, 3.25, 3.75, 3.2, 3.41, 3.83, 
3.63)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to reshape the data from "wide" to "long", with some controlling/grouping variables, then passing to `ggplot2`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
test |>
  mutate(grp = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(Type, grp)) |>
  mutate(across(c(Type, grp), ~ factor(.))) |>
  mutate(x = row_number(), .by = grp) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, value, linetype = Type, color = grp)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: sample ggplot of test]

I don't think `grp` is all that informative here, you can suppress the legend by including `+ guides(color="none")`.

---

Data

```r
test <- structure(list(Type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Test1 = c(0.5, 1, 0.25, 0.75, 0.2, 0.41, 0.83, 0.63), Test2 = c(1.5, 2, 1.25, 1.75, 1.2, 1.41, 1.83, 1.63), Test3 = c(2.5, 3, 2.25, 2.75, 2.2, 2.41, 2.83, 2.63), Test4 = c(3.5, 4, 3.25, 3.75, 3.2, 3.41, 3.83, 3.63)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```